# Why does NLTK fail to cache pickled data files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, caching, nltk, system-calls

I need to clean, tokenize and lemmatize some free-form text columns that have been extracted from a database. I'm using Python 3.8 and 3.9, along with NLTK, and I'm following this boiled-down procedure:

- lowercase the input
- remove accented chars (leaving plain ASCII)
- tokenize (using NLTK's RegexpTokenizer)
- remove numbers
- remove special chars
- remove contractions
- remove stopwords (using NLTK's TokTokenizer), and finally
- lemmatizing, using NLTK's WordNetLemmatizer

This works *ok* - I'm able to run this over 1000 records in around 80 seconds on a newish laptop (8 core Intel core-i7, 16Gb ram, ssd). Annoyingly, I'm getting similar timings for an AWS Graviton2 (8 cores, 32Gb ram, ssd).

I have discovered that my script is burning cycles doing these operations hundreds of times a second:

```
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/jmcp/nltk_data", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=54, ...}, 0) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/jmcp/nltk_data", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=54, ...}, 0) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/jmcp/nltk_data/taggers/averaged_perceptron_tagger/averaged_perceptron_tagger.pickle", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=6138625, ...}, 0) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/jmcp/nltk_data/taggers/averaged_perceptron_tagger/averaged_perceptron_tagger.pickle", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=6138625, ...}, 0) = 0
```

I haven't been able to figure out why this repeated `stat()` is happening, and I'd appreciate suggestions on how I can avoid it entirely.